# Passport LocaStrategy signup redirect issue

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, passport.js, mean-stack

I am trying to redirect user after signup on Passport

```
passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
usernameField : 'username',
passwordField : 'password',
passReqToCallback : true},
function(req, username, password, done) {

    // asynchronous
    // User.findOne wont fire unless data is sent back
    process.nextTick(function() {

    // find a user whose username is the same as the forms username
    User.findOne({ username :  username }, function(err, user) {
        // if there are any errors, return the error
        if (err)
            return done(err);
        if (user) {
            return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'Username is already taken.'));
        } else {
            var newUser = new User();
            newUser.username = username;
            newUser.password = password;
            newUser.email = req.body.email;
            newUser.save(function(err) { // create user
                if (err) {
                    return next(err);
                } else {
                    var site = new Site({user : newUser.username, siteTitle: newUser.username});
                    site.save(function(err) { // create website
                        if (err) {
                            return next(err);
                        } else {
                        newUser.sites.push(site); // push site'id in sites field in user
                        newUser.save(); // save user after site'id has been push
                        };
                    });
                };
            res.redirect('users/' + username);
            });
            ...
```

and I get **ReferenceError: res is not defined**

Any help would be appreciated as I am starting Mean dev.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Don't use `res.redirect(..)`, use normal `done` callback then handle the response appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be handling redirects in here - the function of the strategy is to determine whether the user is authenticated or not.

Redirects can then be done in the middleware:

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
                     successRedirect: '/',
                     failureRedirect: '/login'
}));
```

http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate/